# Are FindFirstFile, FindNextFile APIs unreliable?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory, ntfs

For my purpose I was looking to optimize ways of recursively enumerating subfolders from a given folder on the NTFS file system on Windows, and I came across this little "*gem*" from the Microsoft's page for the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API:

> **Note**  In rare cases or on a heavily loaded system, file attribute
>   information on NTFS file systems may not be current at the time this
>   function is called. To be assured of getting the current NTFS file
>   system file attributes, call the [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

So, let me try to understand it.

I do rely on the `dwFileAttributes` parameter returned in the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` struct to tell a file from a folder. So what this note suggests is that in some cases I might get some bogus result, right? If so, why not fix it in one of their updates instead of posting it here?

And also their suggested workaround of using GetFileInformationByHandle API. How exactly am I supposed to call it? It takes a file handle. So do they really want us to open each file that the `FindNextFile` returns and call `GetFileInformationByHandle` on it? Can you imagine "how far" my optimization would go with such approach?

Anyway, it'd be nice if someone could shed some light on this...

Comment: The values returned by FindXxxFile are advisory and not authoritative. See discussion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/26/10251026.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Distinguishing a file from a folder will be OK, because that information is likely to be constant.  Files aren't being turned into folders or folders into files.

The documentation says "may not be current" because other processes may be changing attributes, and without a locking mechanism to synchronize the attributes are being written lazily. If your application requires absolutely current info, you retrieve it ...ByHandle which insures that the information is current.

Comment: "likely to be constant" is an understatement. The information can only be out of date when someone has a handle open for writing, and you can't change a file into a folder while someone is writing to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way every status-reporting function works. At best, it reports the status at some undefined point in-between when you called the function and when the function returned. But it doesn't "freeze the world" to ensure that the data is still valid later.

Rather than noting this on every single function, documentation typically only notes it on functions that tend to lead to severe problems, particularly security problems, when this is not taken into account.

If you open a file and get a handle to it, you are assured that all your operations using that handle will be to the same underlying file. But when you perform operations by name, there is no such assurance. Files can be created, deleted, and renamed. So the same name may not later refer to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

`dwFileAttributes` is not something that is going to be unreliable when it comes to telling the difference between files and folders. I think that note is referring to information that might be cached for update by the file system (modified/accessed timestamps, etc) but whether an item is a file or a folder is not something that is going to change.

Comment: Unless someone deletes a file/folder and then renames a folder/file to the same name.

Comment: But they can also do that after FindNextFile returns, so there is no new problem here. You have to deal with that possibility even if FindNextFile always returned current data.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Exactly. That's one of the reasons the warning is there. (Some status-reporting functions have a history of being misused or have particularly severe consequences if misused, and it is customary to include a warning that the results may not be current.)